Consistency Issues in GPU usage reports with Slurm's sreport
I'm observing inconsistencies in the data reported about GPU usage by Slurm's sreport command; here's the output for the GPU usage:
$ sreport -thourper cluster utilization --tres=gres/gpu start=2024-04-01 end=2024-05-01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster Utilization 2024-04-01T00:00:00 - 2024-04-30T23:59:59
Usage reported in TRES Hours/Percentage of Total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster      TRES Name         Allocated              Down              Idle            Reported 
--------- -------------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- ------------------- 
 hyperion       gres/gpu      25826(6.22%)       6270(1.51%)    382941(92.27%)      415037(95.91%)

Besides I don't really understand why the reported total doesn't reach the 100%, only a 6.22% of GPU allocation looked really low to me, so I checked all GRES types and I got the following output (cropped):
$ sreport -thourper cluster utilization --tres=ALL start=2024-04-01 end=2024-05-01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster Utilization 2024-04-01T00:00:00 - 2024-04-30T23:59:59
Usage reported in TRES Hours/Percentage of Total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Cluster      TRES Name        Allocated              Down              Idle            Reported 
--------- -------------- ---------------- ----------------- ----------------- -------------------
 hyperion       gres/gpu     25826(6.22%)       6270(1.51%)    382941(92.27%)      415037(95.91%) 
 hyperion gres/gpu:rtx3+     3365(25.97%)      4323(33.36%)      5271(40.67%)      12960(100.00%) 
 hyperion  gres/gpu:a100    22460(64.99%)       1508(4.36%)     10592(30.65%)      34560(100.00%) 
 hyperion gres/gpu:a6000         0(0.02%)       180(25.02%)       540(74.96%)        720(100.00%) 
 hyperion   gres/gpu:a30         0(0.00%)       259(99.28%)          2(0.72%)         261(18.14%)

The following text is extracted from the slurm.conf documentation page:
"Given a configuration of "AccountingStorageTRES=gres/gpu,gres/gpu:tesla,gres/gpu:volta" Then "gres/gpu:tesla" and "gres/gpu:volta" will track only jobs that explicitly request those two GPU types, while "gres/gpu" will track allocated GPUs of any type ("tesla", "volta" or any other GPU type)."
So, this is that specific parameter in our slurm.conf file:
AccountingStorageTRES=gres/gpu,gres/gpu:rtx3090,gres/gpu:a100,gres/gpu:a6000,gres/gpu:a30
However, we finally decided to enforce users to select a specific GPU model through the job_submit.lua script when submitting a job.
As I understand it, in the report, the gres/gpu line should either be at 0 because no one can use just the gres/gpu option without specifying a concrete GPU model, or it should have the total data related to all the GPU models, corresponding to the lines gres/gpu:xxx.
In fact, the sum of the values Allocated and Down columns of each gres/gpu:xxx line exactly matches the values of the gres/gpu line, but there's something wrogn with the values of the Idle column that causes all the discrepancy.
This is not a major issue since I can extract all the correct data by making specific GPU model queries, but I would like to know what could be happening here.
Could someone have any idea?
Thanks in advance!
